# Paypal Sandbox - notify url issue

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am developing online store application and I have difficult struggle with recieving order information to my notify url. Following [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) I have created my paypal form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="buy" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buy" id="">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test-facilitator@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My online store">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" data-bind="value: amount"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="myurl/notify">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="myurl/return">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="myurl/cancel">
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

where "myurl" is something like `http://78.83.22.112`. I am running my application on local apache server.
Return and cancel urls are working as expected, but it seems like Paypal cannot call my notify url. I am developing my application with Laravel 4, so here is how i manage my notify url in routes.php:

```
Route::post('/notify', 'CartController@notify');
```

This is my notify method:

```
public function notify() {

    Log::info("Notify hit");

}
```

Tested my notify url in the IPN simulator, the result is

> We're sorry, we could not connect to this URL. Please make sure it was entered correctly.

What am I doing wrong ? Why sandbox cannot call my notify url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 3 days battle finally resolved this. Instead of typing "localhost" in my browser, I have typed my external IP - the one that I am sending to Paypal, to test my application. And my notify URL was called successfull. No idea why, but this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a firewall issue. Remember, cancel and return URLs are where PayPal sends **you** to a URL. I regularly test against internal non-routing URLs all the time. PayPal simply sends your browser where you tell it and does no validation on whether or not anyone can reach it.

IPN is a different story. PayPal's server must be able to connect to the URL you specify. In this case, you need to have port 80(http) open so outside users can connect. Microsoft has [instructions on how to open a firewall port](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) (Windows 7 but similar for 8.1, etc).

Comment: I am using windows 7 and unblocked port 80 - nothing changes. Maybe that is not the case or I am doing something wrong..

Comment: Are you behind a residential router? You'll have to open that port and forward it to your machine as well.

Comment: Not sure what residential router means, I am using PON device. Good to know is that my application is absolutely accessible from other machines, I am accessing it from my office. But cannot be accessed by paypal.

Comment: Is it possible sanbox not to accept IP for notify_url ? Maybe it can be only domain name ? Just hitting in the dark..

Comment: Network Address Translation. if you have a wireless router there's a 99% chance it's doing this firewall work for you. IPN should work with any valid internet address, even an IP.

Comment: Well, I do not have router. As I said, I am with optical internet with PON device without wireless. Not sure if those devices have firewall, I have very limited access to my device configuration.

Comment: Well, go find an internet tool to see if something can connect to your URL

Comment: I have tested it with some tools, it is 100 % accessible..absolutely strange case.